# Retrieving 1D arrays from NetCDF char array variables in HDF5 files using Java

Tags: java, string, char, hdf5, netcdf

Using the Java API for NetCDF, I have an HDF5 file with an array of type CHAR, which according to the [documentation](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/CDM/DataType.html) is similar to strings containing only ASCII characters: "The char type contains uninterpreted characters, one character per byte. Typically these contain 7-bit ASCII characters." In HDFView, an example of one of thee values in the array is "13".

I know that for an array of integers I can get them all as a Java array like this:

```
int[] data = (int[]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(int.class);
```

But how do I get back an array of this CHAR type? Unfortunately the documentation I referenced is of no help.

The following cannot be correct, because some of the items are more than single characters:

```
char[] data = (char[]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(char.class);
```

The following attempts all throw a `ForbiddenConversionException`:

```
char[] data = (char[]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(char.class);
char[][] data = (char[][]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(char[].class);
String[] data = (String[]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(String.class);
```

If I use `netCDFArray.toString()` I see my array of strings, because `ArrayChar` uses a `StringIterator`. I too could use such an iterator and do something with each string, I suppose. But I don't need to get an int iterator to retrieve integers. How can I efficiently retrieve all strings of a CHAR type in one go, analogous to how I can retrieve integers (see above)? I would be content with retrieving a Java `Strings[]`, `CharSequence[]`, or `char[][]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a NetCDF string of type CHAR is represented logically as a two-dimensional array of type `char`, but internally it is stored as a single array of type `char`. Therefore, the most efficient way to retrieve the data is the following:

```
char[] data = (char[]) netCDFArray.get1DJavaArray(char.class);
```

One must then extract the individual strings from this single array:

```
assert netCDFArray.getRank()==2 : "Expected a two-dimensional logical array of chars.";
int stringLength=netCDFArray.getShape()[1];
int stringCount=netCDFArray.getShape()[0];
//iterate through stringCount positions of stringLength length
```

The added twist is that apparently strings are stored as zero-terminated, that is, the supposedly fixed-length strings apparently may be variable-length strings of less than *stringLength* using ASCII 0 as a delimiter. I derived this from the code; I couldn't find it in the [documentation](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/CDM/DataType.html).